# How to Print Large SSIS Layout Package to PDF

Tags: visual-studio, pdf, ssis, screenshot

Hi I Have Question about Print SSIS Packages
because when i tried to print using CTRL+P the size max of paper is A3

and when i try to print using A3 to PDF some layout become cutoff irregular.
I tried using snipping tools , snagit, etc. It will be a big problem to make sure the join the screnshot.

Any Idea about proper tools to print or export?

Comment: @KJ i tried using XPS print, and the problem same, no bigger than A3

Comment: I am edit and manage SSIS SSDT Visual studio there are no configuration to print proper Package/ETL Flow

Comment: @KJ i dont think so, because that link is to reformat SSRS layout not SSIS package